# How to make JSON array with JSONObject android java

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, while-loop

```js
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select *,t1.mysql_sys_id AS surveyid" +
  ",t1.status AS activestatus" +
  ",t2.survey_id AS questiosurveyid" +
  ",t2.mysql_sys_id AS questiosysid" +
  ",t3.mysql_sys_id AS answerid" +
  ",t3.question_id AS answerquestionid" +
  ",t3.survey_id AS answersurveyid" +
  ",t4.survey_id AS dependendsurveyid" +
  ",t4.question_id AS dependendquestionid" +
  ",t4.answer_id AS dependendanswerid" +
  ",t4.survey_id AS nestsurveyid" +
  ",t4.question_id AS nestquestionid" +
  " from " +
  "survey_tbl AS t1 LEFT JOIN " +
  "question_tbl AS t2 ON t1.mysql_sys_id = t2.survey_id  LEFT JOIN " +
  "answer_tbl AS t3 ON t1.mysql_sys_id = t3.survey_id AND t2.sys_id = t3.question_id  LEFT JOIN " +
  "dependent_question_tbl AS t4 ON t1.mysql_sys_id = t4.survey_id AND t2.mysql_sys_id = t4.question_id AND t3.sys_id = t4.answer_id  LEFT JOIN " +
  "nest_question_tbl AS t5 ON t1.mysql_sys_id = t4.survey_id AND t2.mysql_sys_id = t5.question_id  WHERE" +
  " t1.status = 'active' AND " +
  "t1.mysql_sys_id = " + id + " ", null);

res.moveToFirst();

JSONObject jj = new JSONObject();
JSONArray survey = new JSONArray();
JSONArray question = new JSONArray();
JSONArray answer = new JSONArray();
JSONArray dependent = new JSONArray();
JSONArray nest = new JSONArray();
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
Set < String > questionCodes = new HashSet < String > ();
Set < String > depquestionCodes = new HashSet < String > ();
Set < String > nestquestionCodes = new HashSet < String > ();
while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
  JSONObject k = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject l = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject m = new JSONObject();
  JSONObject n = new JSONObject();

  j.put("surveyid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("surveyid")));
  j.put("surveynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_num")));
  j.put("surveytitle", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_title")));
  j.put("surveydescription", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("survey_description")));
  j.put("startdate", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("start_date")));
  j.put("enddate", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("end_date")));
  j.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("activestatus")));


  String questionCode = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questiosysid"));
  if (questionCodes.contains(questionCode)) {
    continue;


  } else {
    k.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questiosysid")));
    k.put("questiondisplaynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_display_order")));
    k.put("questiosysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("questiosysid")));
    k.put("questionorder", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_order")));
    k.put("questioncategory", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question_category")));
    k.put("question", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("question")));
    k.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("activestatus")));
    question.put(k);
  }

  l.put("displaynum", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("input_display_order")));
  l.put("answerid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerid")));
  l.put("surveyid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answersurveyid")));
  l.put("questionid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answerquestionid")));
  l.put("inputtype", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("input_type")));
  l.put("inputname", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("input_name")));
  l.put("inputname", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("input_other")));
  l.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("activestatus")));

  String depquestionCode = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("mysql_sys_id"));
  if (depquestionCodes.contains(depquestionCode)) {
    continue;


  } else {
    m.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("mysql_sys_id")));
    m.put("surveyid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dependendsurveyid")));
    m.put("questionid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dependendquestionid")));
    m.put("referralid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("referral_id")));
    m.put("answerid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("dependendanswerid")));
    m.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("activestatus")));
    dependent.put(m);
  }
  String nestquestionCode = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("mysql_sys_id"));
  if (nestquestionCodes.contains(nestquestionCode)) {
    continue;


  } else {
    n.put("mysqlsysid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("mysql_sys_id")));
    n.put("surveyid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nestsurveyid")));
    n.put("questionid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("nestquestionid")));
    n.put("referralid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("referral_id")));
    n.put("answerid", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("answer_id")));
    n.put("status", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("activestatus")));
    nest.put(n);
  }



  answer.put(l);



  res.moveToNext();


}

survey.put(j);

jj.put("answer", answer);
jj.put("question", question);
jj.put("dependent", dependent);
jj.put("nest", nest);
jj.put("survey", survey);
finalmyArray.put(jj);
```

I am selecting multiple tables using `LEFT JOIN`. In the example above I am getting extra value for each question because I have multiple answers.

**Scenario:**

In my question table I have 1 entry.
In my answer table I have 3 entry.

What happens is the question object will have 3 entries because of the iteration for answer table.

**GOAL**

What I want to achieve is for the question object to contain only 1 entry since in database there is only 1. And for the answer object to contain 3 entry since in database there are 3.

Assumption: I think this is cause by iteration on the answer table.

I tried having a check inside the while loop but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

use this method.its very easy. just pass cursor in this method and method returns JSONArray .

```
public static JSONArray CreateJsonRecords(Cursor cursor)
            throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArry = null;

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            jsonArry = new JSONArray();
            do {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                for (int k = 0; k < cursor.getColumnCount(); k++) {
                    jsonObject
                            .put(cursor.getColumnName(k), cursor.getString(k));
                }

                jsonArry.put(jsonObject);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

        return jsonArry;
    }
```

**In this method ,you must have to create jsonArray like as database field name same JsonObject Key.so if you want to use my method then its compulsory to database field name same as jsonobject Key name.**

Comment: `database field name same as jsonobject Key name` by this you mean for example `[{answer:1},{answer:2}]` where answer is the column name ni database?

Comment: this is something different from the format i am creating in my OP but can i change the format to match the way i do it in my OP
?

Comment: no Original Post.. in my post the format is not the same as function will produce i will to do something to make them the same